Yup Validation for Date
I'm encountering an issue with Yup validation in a Formik form regarding a date field. I want to prevent users from selecting future dates. Currently, the validation only triggers when I click the save button, but I want an error to be thrown immediately if a future date is selected.(like other text field Yup validations)
Here's how I've set up the validation:
schema = Yup.date()
.required(${item.validation.required.message})
.max(new Date(), "No Future Date, Please choose another date");
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape(schema);
I expected the validation to prevent users from selecting future dates immediately after they've been selected. However, the validation only seems to occur upon clicking the save button.
Could anyone guide me on how to modify the validation to throw an error immediately upon selecting a future date?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Make sure you have written your expression correctly. I see that you have not taken the expression you defined in Shape as an Object. If you use it as follows, your problem will be solved. You can see the detailed usage in the official document.
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    date: Yup.date().max(new Date(),'You cannot choose a future date!').required('Date field is required!'),
  });

